# Fabric beta testing: I can't install beta app

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm using fabric for beta testing.

I got a notification about beta app from Crashlytics. The title is "XXX v1.0.0 (5) is ready to test".

I expected that I could see a download button on the install page, but I could not find it.

How should I do next? Any help will be appreciated.

I have attached the screen shot.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: In that screenshot it says "The developer needs to upload a build for this distribution".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and my solution was ensure that the development provisioning profile is used to build the app.

In my case, i had two different provisioning profiles, one for distribution and one for development. I used fastlane with gym to build the archive. My failure was to not specify what profile it should use.

The failure happened by invoking gym without explicitly saying to use the dev profile:

```
gym
```

The solution was to add the export_method with development.

```
gym(export_method: 'development')
```

In this case it will use the development provisioning profile.

If you don't use fastlane, please ensure that the used profile is matching the one you have specified in the crashlytics beta setup.

Good Luck Everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry.. the reason was just very slow uploading. I got an email and then I found install button.

Comment: How long did it take for you to finally see an install button?

Comment: I suspect what he is referring to is that fabric does not handle very slow internet connections well at all. I have seen this happen as well when the upload takes forever....